# $B^HB=b$ number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let B any non square real matrix $m\times n$ with linearly independent columns.

$B^HB=b$ (where $B^H$: conjugate transpose of Β) has only one solution for every $b\in R^m\neq0 $ (1)

Is (1) true or false and why?

Comment: What is the size of $B^H B$? What is its rank?

Comment: No info has been given for $B^HB$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $B$ is injective since it has a linearly independent columns and then
$$\langle B^HB x,x\rangle=\langle B x,Bx\rangle=||Bx||^2=0\iff Bx=0\iff x=0$$
so $B^HB$ is symmetric definite positive matrix hence it's invertible. Conclude.